# Display response(xml) by making a HTTP GET request using javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, xml

I have very new to JS and I have done my research but I guess I'm kind of using the wrong technique or something.
Like in python to make GET request we do:

```
request_text = requests.get(url).text
```

I want to do the same thing but using JS i.e. display the content from `"http://synd.cricbuzz.com/j2me/1.0/livematches.xml"` in the raw(xml) format and I have found this script somewhere but it doesn't work.

```
<h2>AJAX</h2>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>

<p id="demo"></p>


<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://synd.cricbuzz.com/j2me/1.0/livematches.xml", false);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I just need the direction on how to do the same i.e. how to send a GET/POST request using JS and render it on a webpage?

Comment: Due to the same origin policy for client-side script in the browser the XMLHttpRequest to a different origin than your server is only possible if the other server is set up for CORS.

Answer (score 1):

When I use

```js
function test(url) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('GET', url);
  req.onload = function() {
    var section = document.createElement('section');
    var h2 = document.createElement('h2');
    h2.textContent = 'Received from ' + url;
    section.appendChild(h2);
    var pre = document.createElement('pre');
    pre.textContent = req.responseText;
    section.appendChild(pre);
    document.body.appendChild(section);
  };
  req.onerror = function(evt) {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<p>Error requesting ' + url + '.<\/p>');
  };
  req.send();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  test('http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/cdtest/test2011060701.xml');
  test('http://synd.cricbuzz.com/j2me/1.0/livematches.xml');
},
false);
```

the first URL works as the server is set up to allow the [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) request for that directory while the second fails as the server does not allow it. So unless you serve your HTML with the script from `synd.cricbuzz.com` or unless you can change the configuration of `synd.cricbuzz.com` to allow a CORS request you won't be able to request the XML from that server.

Note also that in modern browsers (current versions of Mozilla, Chrome, Edge) you can use the `Promise` based `fetch` method instead of `XMLHttpRequest`, as shown below. But the same origin policy is not different for `fetch`, so the same as stated above holds.

```js
function test(url) {
  fetch(url).then(function(response) {
    if(response.ok) {
      response.text().then(function(text) {
        var section = document.createElement('section');
        var h2 = document.createElement('h2');
        h2.textContent = 'Received from ' + url;
        section.appendChild(h2);
        var pre = document.createElement('pre');
        pre.textContent = text;
        section.appendChild(pre);
        document.body.appendChild(section);
      });
    }
    else {
      document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<p>Error requesting ' + url + '; status: ' + response.status + '.<\/p>');
    }
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<p>Error "' + error.message + '" requesting ' + url + '.<\/p>');
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  test('http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/cdtest/test2011060701.xml');
  test('http://synd.cricbuzz.com/j2me/1.0/livematches.xml');
},
false);
```